# extract data-tag from a json result

Tags: javascript, json

This is the result of my API request:

```
// API callback
showAuth({
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "entry": {
        "content": {
            "type": "html",
            "$t": "\u003Cdiv id=\"data\" class=\"democlass\" data-author=\"Mr. Jhon Doe\" data-cat=\"Technology\" data-url=\"http:\/\/www.qbtemplates.com\/\"\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E \u003Cimg alt=\"Treasury : Minimal Responsive News \u0026 Magazine Blogger Template\" src=\"https:\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-Kv_-Jg5krkA\/V8PFfwe1ikI\/AAAAAAAAAU0\/4J4Dlc0lOJIW2Qbe45TDTMVo4_Ij8MQhACLcB\/s1600\/Treasury---http___treasury-soratemplates.blogspot.co.jpg\" title=\"Treasury : Minimal Responsive News \u0026 Magazine Blogger Template\" \/\u003E\u003Cbr \/\u003E \u003C!-- \u003Cul class=\"item-cta\"\u003E    \u003Cli class=\"demo\"\u003E        \u003Ca data-demo=\"true\" href=\"http:\/\/treasury-soratemplates.blogspot.com\/\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003EPreview\u003C\/a\u003E    \u003C\/li\u003E    \u003Cli class=\"download\"\u003E        \u003Ca data-download=\"true\" href=\"http:\/\/qbtemplates.16mb.com\/files\/Treasury%20Free%20Version.zip\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003EDownload\u003C\/a\u003E    \u003C\/li\u003E\u003C\/ul\u003E--\u003E \u003Cbr \/\u003E\u003Cdiv style=\"text-align: justify;\"\u003ETreasury is all purpose Blogging blogger theme which can be used for all your blogs like travel, food, life, programming, everyday, fashion and everything you want to blog about. On top of this, great and friendly support makes your website setup experience completely smooth! Treasury Magazine design is excellent for a news, newspaper, magazine, article and editorial publishing or review and rating site. It uses the best clean SEO practices, and on top of that, it’s fast, simple, and easy to use. \u003C\/div\u003E"
        },
        "author": [{
            "name": {
                "$t": "Mikey"
            },
            "uri": {
                "$t": "http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/profile\/05775556662956xxxxxx"
            },
            "email": {
                "$t": "noreply@blogger.com"
            },
            "gd$image": {
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail",
                "width": "16",
                "height": "16",
                "src": "http:\/\/img1.blogblog.com\/img\/b16-rounded.gif"
            }
        }],
    }
});
```

I just trying to extract some data into variable

```
function showAuth(user) {
    var b = user.entry.author[0];
    c = b.name.$t;
    d = b.gd$image.src.replace(/\/s[0-9]+(-*c*)\//, '/s60$1/');
    e = user.entry.content.$t[0];
    f = e.data - author;
    document.write('<img class="auvtar" alt="' + c + '" src="' + d + '" title="' + c + '"/>' + f + '')
}
```

The variable `c` and `d` result the correct data, but the variable `f` result no data ( I mean the entire code isn't functioning if I enable the variable `f`).

I want to extract the `data-cat`, `data-author`, and `data-url` from `entry.content` into separated variables, like `f`, `g`, and `h`.

Comment: Tried removing the `[0]` from $t?

Comment: just trying it, but still the same problem

Comment: What does `e` log?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: author is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the [0] in

- e = user.entry.content.$t[0];

then convert it to an html element;

- g = $(e)[0]; // index 0 is the div, you could replace this if you
  want to find a specific element

and finally you can use it as jQuery object and extract the data values:

- h = $(g).data('author')
- i = $(g).data('cat')
- j = $(g).data('url')

Cheers!

Comment: did I miss something? convert it to `e=user.entry.content.$t;` but the result is `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: you need to add jQuery library, I will provide an answer for a plain javascript

Comment: no problem, just in case you still need the plain javascript way, create first a div element to hold, div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = e; g = div.childNodes[0]; then you can access data by g.getAttribute('data-author')

Answer (score 0):

`e.data` is `undefined`.

You are setting `e` to `user.entry.content.$t[0]`

This means that `e` is the first character in `$t` which appears to be the long string starting with: `"\u003Cdiv id=\"data\" class=\"d`

Comment: so how your suggestion to resolve this? already trying to modify some code but still no results...